# mongoose, find data based on request

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I want to customize my search crateria on mongoose collection based on request parameter

```
Course.find(
      {
        instTypeId: 1,
        status: 1,
        "institute.instId": req.body.instId,
        "institute.majorId": req.body.majorId
      },
    )
```

I tried to do that but if the req.intId or req.major id is empty it only get the records that have empty institute.instId

In case the req.intId or req.major or both I dont want to include them in the find

Comment: What kind of `request` data are you expecting? from query parameter or body? or is req something else?

Comment: req = request.body, I am expecting that the two values would be empty or one of them is not or both are not empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let search = {
  instTypeId: 1,
  status: 1
};
if (req.body.instId) {
  search["institute.instId"] = req.body.instId;
}
if (req.body.majorId) {
  search["institute.majorId"] = req.body.majorId;
}
Course.find(search)
```

I did that in order to customize the search columns

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Object.assign` to add values to the search object if they exist:

```
let instId;
let majorId = 1;

if (instId){
  search = Object.assign(search, {"institute.instId": instId});
}
if (majorId){
  search = Object.assign(search, {"institute.majorId": majorId});
}

Course.find(search , (err, foundCourses) => {
    // Do stuff
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you're receiving parsed `req.body`, quick and dirty way could be:

```
Course.find({
  instTypeId: 1,
  status: 1,
  // if req.body.instId is 'undefined', then it returns false so the expression returns 'null'
  "institute.instId": req.body.instId || null,
  "institute.majorId": req.body.majorId || null
})
```

You can build query object in similar fashion:

```
var query = {}
if (req.body.instId) {
  // using object destructuring
  query = {..., "institute.instId": req.body.instId }
}
```

However, it is advisable to set up some validation depending on use case